# Call ReplaceFile Winapi using Extern.Declare

Tags: winapi, vbscript, hp-uft, kernel32

I am trying to call the ReplaceFile API from UFT.

Here is my script:

```
Option Explicit
 
Private Const REPLACEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH=1
Private Const REPLACEFILE_IGNORE_MERGE_ERRORS=2
Private Const REPLACEFILE_IGNORE_ACL_ERRORS=4

Extern.Declare micInteger, "ReplaceFile", "Kernel32.dll", "ReplaceFileA", micString, micString, micString, micDWord, micLong, micLong
Dim lpReplacedFileName: lpReplacedFileName="C:\TEMP\T\alt.dat"
Dim lpReplacementFileName: lpReplacementFileName="C:\TEMP\T\neu.dat"
Dim lpBackupFileName: lpBackupFileName="C:\TEMP\T\bak.dat"
Dim dwReplaceFlags: dwReplaceFlags=REPLACEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH
Dim lpExclude: lpExclude=NULL
Dim lpReserved: lpReserved=NULL
     

Dim Result:
Result=Extern.ReplaceFile (lpReplacedFileName, lpReplacementFileName, lpBackupFileName, 0, lpExclude, lpReserved)
MsgBox GetLastError ()
```

If I now create a file alt.dat in c:\temp, it does not get renamed to neu.dat when the script runs. Result is 0, GetLastError returns 0, which probably means: The API function was not called, and Extern.Declare did not tell me what I did wrong.

So what do I do wrong?

Comment: If the function returned 0, then it was successful. `GetLastError` will only give you a meaningful value if the call failed. Does the call work if you use `ReplaceFileW`?

Comment: @theB: [Per the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365512.aspx), `ReplaceFile()` returns 0 on failure, not success. If `GetLastError()` is not returning an error code on failure, then my guess would be that `Extern` itself is likely resetting `GetLastError()` after `ReplaceFile()` exits and before the script has a chance to call `GetLastError()`.

Comment: Good catch @Remy.  It's my fault for playing around with too many non-zero returns today.  It does make me more suspicious that there's a string conversion issue. If the strings are actually UTF-16 encoded, then only the first character of the path string will make it out to the function, which means that the call is equivalent to `ReplaceFile("C","C","C",0,0,0)`

Comment: But I am calling ReplaceFileA, not ReplaceFileW.

Comment: Meanwhile, I agree it probably is a character set encoding/representation issue, will explore further and report any solution(s) found